# Creating a function that can return a list items in using Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I am looking to create a function in Oracle where I can pass a value as a string and return a list. For example I would like to have a function where I give it the title of a book and it returns a list of users who own that book.

I have created the function below which contains warnings which I'm not sure how to fix and whether it is the right way to go about it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function UsersForBooks
    ( name_in IN varchar(250) )
    RETURN varchar(250)
IS
    listToReturn varchar(250);
    cursor c1 is
            SELECT username
              FROM (GC_User NATURAL JOIN GC_Books) 
      NATURAL JOIN GC_BookOwnership
             WHERE GC_Books.title = name_in
    ;
BEGIN
   open c1;
   fetch c1 into listToReturn;
   close c1;
   RETURN listToReturn;
END;
/
```

I am calling my function in the following way and not sure if it is correct.

```
SELECT * FROM UsersForBooks('The Da Vinci Code');
```

Comment: It is not correct, but it would be helpful if you tell us what the warnings are, and what output you get when you call it.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have "lists". What are you trying to return, a delimited string?

Comment: I'm effectively trying to return a table of users who own a certain book. Basically I want a function where a value can be passed to the SELECT statement and the result of this select statement to be returned, which in this case would be a table of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UsersForBooks (name_in IN varchar2)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS

  c SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

  OPEN c FOR
  SELECT...;

  RETURN  c;

END;
/
```

In Oracle always use VARCHAR2 rather than VARCHAR.

You don't specify the size of variables in a parameter list, only in the actual variable declaration.

Comment: Thanks Todd. The function seems to build correctly but running the query SELECT * FROM UsersForBooks('The Da Vinci Code'); comes up with an error stating no sql has been selected when I evidently have.

Comment: Please provide the exact error you're getting.  I have to go now, but maybe someone else can take it from here.

Comment: Many thanks for all the help, this is the error that I get:                  Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    SQLState:  42000
    ErrorCode: 933

Comment: Ok, now post the code of your function and the statement you're using to call it.  You're really making it difficult for anyone to help you.